# Yii - Textfield validation not working

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii framework. Now I'm using two textfields for `min size` and `max size`. Now this textfields are supposed to take only integers. But they are taking alphabets also. I used the following rule in model file.

```
 public function rules() {
return array(
    array('min_size, max_size', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true));
    }
```

But this seems to be not working, no error is displayed . How can i validate successfully, by displaying error when text is entered. Should I make some changes in main.php

Comment: make sure your db has these fields or you have declared them in model, can we see your form where these fields are??? Also check console, if there is no jquery conflict.

Comment: @Coderanonymous This fields are not retrieved from db, they are formed an xml and retrieved from xml

Comment: so declare them in model, and validate, show your form..

Comment: @Coderanonymous In form, it is `<?php echo $form->textField($model,'min_size', array('placeholder' => 'Min Sqft', array('integerOnly'=>'true')); ?><?php echo $form->textField($model,'max_size', array('placeholder' => 'Min Sqft', array('integerOnly'=>'true')); ?>`

Comment: `<?php echo $form->error($model,'min_size'); ?><?php echo $form->error($model,'max_size'); ?>` do you have this in your code?

Comment: also place `$model->validate()` in your controller..

Answer (score 0):

Look for this kind of form in your code

```
<?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'trip-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
    ?>
```

if you want ajax validation to take place then this line must be uncommented in controller

```
 $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
```

Client validation will automatically take place

Comment: I don't see this line anywhere in controller

Comment: This line is present at the declaration of the form

Answer (score 0):

Just try Adding this instead of that

```
if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === "your_form_id") {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
```

This will check with the model when the ajax request is received

Comment: Where should I add this in controller, inside any function or what

Comment: add this in the action from where your form is rendered

Comment: No Valiadtion did not happen. Now, I added ajaxvalidation function and I'm trying now

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === "yw0") {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($search_model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }`...Nothing works

Comment: This is just a number validation and doesnt need a ajax validation only to work??
Let me know if the Client validation works

Comment: I made the client validation and it works, but I'm asked to do even server valiadtion. See browsers are not supporting client validation

Comment: i Dont know why you want a server validation because we can prevent wrong data being given even in a client validation.
Server Validations are for the case of Unique usernames, unique email id, etc